# Problems with binary strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, binary

I am currently trying to make my Ruby script output the following:

"\x41" * 28 "\x42\x13\x40\x00"

My code is:

```
puts "\x41" * 28 "\x42\x13\x40\x00"
```

instead of outputting it as you might expect it outputs:
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB‼@

I know that this is the "translated" values but how do I avoid this translation? I have been looking into .pack() but I could not figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Dar56

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
puts "\\x41" * 28 + "\\x42\\x13\\x40\\x00"
```

or

```
puts '\x41' * 28 + '\x42\x13\x40\x00'
```

Case 1 works because `\\` is an escape sequence meaning a `\` while case 2 works because the literals inside `''` only check for the `\'` and `\\` escape sequences.